# New-Hire Script issues

Tags: powershell

I have written a script that grabs information from a CSV file and is supposed to create an AD account and an MSOL account based upon the variables that are put in the columns. The script works with just one user that I tested.

```
$AccountList = import-csv "C:\File\path\input.csv"

ForEach ($Person in $AccountList) {
    $Accountname = $firstname.Trim().ToLower() + "." + $lastname.Trim().ToLower()
    $Firstname = $AccountList.pFirstName
    $LastName = $AccountList.pLastName
    $UPN = $Accountname + "@company.com"
    $displayname = $firstname + " " + $Lastname
    $Department = $AccountList.pDepartment
    $Location = $AccountList.pLocation|

    ForEach {
        New-ADUser -SamAccountName $Accountname -Name $displayname -DisplayName $displayname -Surname $Lastname -GivenName $Firstname -UserPrincipalName $UPN -Department $Department -Office $Location -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "X" -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Enabled $true -PasswordNeverExpires $false -Path "CN=Users,DC=medsinmotion,DC=local"
    }
    ForEach ($Person in $AccountList) {
        New-MsolUser -DisplayName $displayname -FirstName $Firstname -LastName $Lastname -UserPrincipalName $UPN -Department $Department  -UsageLocation US -LicenseAssignment reseller-account:DESKLESSPACK -ForceChangePassword $true

        if ($Department -match "Call Center" -or "Retail") {
            Add-MailboxPermission -Identity CallCenter -User $Accountname -AccessRights FullAccess
            Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity callctr@company.com -Member $Accountname
        }
        Else { 
            Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalname $UPN -AddLicenses O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM -RemoveLicenses reseller-account:DESKLESSPACK
        }
        Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity all -Member $UPN
    }
}
```

The problem is when there are more than 2 users, it spits out an error for all of the variables that I have tried to set; the error is:

> "Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'SamAccountName'. Specified method is not supported"

and it goes through all of the variables (`Displayname`, `Samaccountname`, and `UPN`) but with that error.

There is no `-Raw` for `Import-Csv` like there is for `Get-Content`.

Is there a way to convert it to system string? Please let me know what the possible solution

*Had to redo it

Comment: At least one issue (there may be more) is that you are referring to `$AccountList` in various places where you should be referring to `$Person`.  For example: `$Firstname = $AccountList.pFirstName`, should be `$Firstname = $Person.pFirstName`

Comment: OK thanks I will have to try it out. I appreciate the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and most major issue as @boxdog mentioned in the comments, is that you are looping over `$AccountList` and each element is `$Person`. So if you want the current element, you should use `$person`.

The second issue was defining `$AccountName` with `$firstname` and `$lastname` before you defined those.

Third you were piping just `$AccountList.pLocation` into another loop.

Fourth, `$Department -match "Call Center" -or "Retail"` would always be true because `$Department -match "Call Center"` and `"Retail"` are separate conditionals and when the string `Retail` is cast to a boolean since it's not empty it would always be true. `|` is the regex or operator otherwise you would need another `-match` statement after the `-or`.

Your script could also be greatly simplified by utilizing [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675931.aspx) to define your parameters in a hashtable and then passing the hashtable as the parameters for your command.

```
$AccountList = import-csv "C:\File\path\input.csv"

ForEach ($Person in $AccountList) {

    $NewUserParams = @{
        GivenName = $Person.pFirstName
        Surname = $Person.pLastName
        SamAccountName = "$($Person.pFirstName.Trim().ToLower()).$($Person.pLastName.Trim().ToLower())"
        UserPrincipalName = "$($Person.pFirstName.Trim().ToLower()).$($Person.pLastName.Trim().ToLower())@company.com"
        Name = "$($Person.pFirstName) $($Person.pLastName)"
        DisplayName = "$($Person.pFirstName) $($Person.pLastName)"
        Department = $Person.pDepartment
        Office = $Person.pLocation
        AccountPassword =  (ConvertTo- SecureString -AsPlainText "X" -Force)
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $True
        Enabled = $True
        PasswordNeverExpires = $False
        Path = "CN=Users,DC=medsinmotion,DC=local"
    }

    New-ADUser @NewUserParams

    $NewMsolUserParams = @{
        FirstName = $NewUserParams.GivenName
        LastName = $NewUserParams.Surname
        UserPrincipalName = $NewUserParams.UserPrincipalName
        DisplayName = $NewUserParams.displayname
        Department = $NewUserParams.Department
        UsageLocation = 'US'
        LicenseAssignment =  'reseller-account:DESKLESSPACK'
        ForceChangePassword = $True
    }

    New-MsolUser @NewMsolUserParams

    if ($NewMsolUserParams.Department -match "Call Center|Retail") {
        Add-MailboxPermission -Identity CallCenter -User $NewUserParams.SamAccountName -AccessRights FullAccess
        Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity callctr@company.com -Member $NewUserParams.SamAccountName
    } Else { 
        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalname $NewUserParams.UserPrincipalName -AddLicenses O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM -RemoveLicenses reseller-account:DESKLESSPACK
    }
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity all -Member $NewUserParams.UserPrincipalName 
}
```

Comment: That is pretty cool I did not know that existed but I will have to try it out

Comment: Thank you though really for the advice

Comment: This works and creates the accounts, but it does not add all of the users to the certain Mailboxes and DL's ; it just adds the last member in the list.

Comment: Is there a way to add all of the users to it at once?

Comment: Check if you made modifications for any extra closing curly braces `}`. The mailbox section should be inside the `foreach` loop, and run against every user. Neither [`Add-MailboxPermission`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/add-mailboxpermission?view=exchange-ps) nor[`Add-DistributionGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/add-distributiongroupmember?view=exchange-ps) take arrays, so you do need to run once for each user inside the loop.